# Discretization of zip codes to US regions in R

Tags: r, case, geocoding, discretization

I would like to discretize data with zip codes into regions

I have character data

sample:

```
zip_code
'45654'
'12321'
'99453'
```

etc

I have 6 categories with rules:

region 1 - NE: 01000-19999

region 2 - SE: 20000-39999

region 3 - MW: 40000-58999,60000-69999

region 4 - SW: 70000-79999,85000-88499

region 5 - MT: 59000-59999,80000-84999,88900-89999

region 6 - PC: 90000-99999

I would like my output to be factor data:

```
region
'MW'
'NE'
'PC'
```

etc

Obviously, I know many ways to discretize the data, but none are clean and elegant (like loops, ifelse, etc)

Is there an elegant way to apply a case with 6 categories to discretize this data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, messy but this can work. I assume you'll have to use character objects since some zip codes start with 0. Obs. replace these numbers with your zip codes.

```
zip_code <- c('1','6','15')
regions <- list(NE = as.character(1:3), 
        SE = as.character(4:6), 
        MW = as.character(7:9), 
        SW = as.character(10:12), 
        MT = as.character(13:15), 
        PC = as.character(16:19))
sapply(zip_code, function(x) names(regions[sapply(regions, function(y) x %in% y)]))

 1    6   15 
"NE" "SE" "MT"
```

Comment: note that this is likely not the most elegant solution, I'm sure someone else will chime in with other soln's

Comment: There may be more elegant solutions but yours is functional, which is a mind frame that I'm having a hard time adapting.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a data.table solution using `foverlaps(...)` and the full US zip code database in package `zipcode` for the example. Note that your definitions of the ranges are deficient: for instance there are zip codes in NH that are outside the `NE` range, and PR is completely missing.

```
library(data.table)  # 1.9.4+
library(zipcode)
data(zipcode)        # database of US zip codes (a data frame)

zips    <- data.table(zip_code=zipcode$zip)
regions <- data.table(region=c("NE" , "SE", "MW", "MW", "SW", "SW", "MT", "MT", "MT", "PC"),
                      start =c(01000,20000,40000,60000,70000,85000,59000,80000,88900,90000),
                      end   =c(19999,39999,58999,69999,79999,88400,59999,84999,89999,99999))
setkey(regions,start,end)
zips[,c("start","end"):=list(as.integer(zip_code),as.integer(zip_code))]
result <- foverlaps(zips,regions)[,list(zip_code,region)]
result[sample(1:nrow(result),10)]   # random sample of the result
#    zip_code region
#  1:    27113     SE
#  2:    36101     SE
#  3:    55554     MW
#  4:    91801     PC
#  5:    20599     SE
#  6:    90250     PC
#  7:    95329     PC
#  8:    63435     MW
#  9:    60803     MW
# 10:    07040     NE
```

`foverlaps(...)` works this way: suppose a data.table x has columns `a` and `b` that represent a range (e.g., `a` <= `b` for all rows), and a data.table `y` has columns `c` and `d` that similarly represent a range. Then `foverlaps(x,y)` finds, for each row in `x`, all the rows in `y` which have overlapping ranges.

In your case we set up the `y` argument as the regions, where the ranges are the beginning and ending zipcodes for each (sub) region. Then we set up `x` as the original zip code database using the actual zip codes (converted to integer) for both the beginning and end of the range.

`foverlaps(...)` is extremely fast. In this case the full US zip code database (>44,000 zipcodes) was processed in about 23 milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try (Using @Scott Chamberlain's data)

```
  with(stack(regions), unique(ind[ave(values %in% zip_code, ind, FUN=I)]))
 #[1] NE SE MT
 #Levels: MT MW NE PC SE SW
```

Or

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
 unnest(regions, region) %>%
                     group_by(region) %>%
                     filter(x %in% zip_code)

 # region x
 #1   NE  1
 #2   SE  6
 #3   MT 15
```

Or

```
 r1 <- vapply(regions, function(x) any(x %in% zip_code), logical(1))
 names(r1)[r1]
 #[1] "NE" "SE" "MT"
```